# Where are unique ReceiveFrom addresses really necessary on MassTransit with RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

### Background

My group are complete noobs with MassTransit and messaging in general.  I understand the simple demos found online, but I'm confused on how to set things up for non-trivial scenarios.  (many producers, many consumers, with consumers communicating back to producers)

We currently make 3rd party web service calls directly from web code via synchronous calls.  Some of them are notoriously slow and unreliable to the point of browser timeouts and YSODs that aren't directly our code's fault.  We want to replace these sync calls with messages and eventual consistency for retries and poison queue.

We also want to replace various scheduled/batch tasks with messaging to get closer to real time processing instead of waiting for next batch to run.

Our website runs on a farm of 6 IIS servers behind a hardware load balancer.  There are 2 additional "application" servers that run the scheduled tasks.  I figure we will put our new worker services on the app servers or maybe even all 8 servers.

### Questions

So...  The "common gotchas" section of the MT docs say that each application needs it's own address.  My question is around what exactly is the definition of application in this case.

I have 6 web servers running the website.  Does each of these need a unique address or can they all just be "rabbitmq://localhost/MyApp/Website".  What if IIS is configured for multiple worker processes?  Do each of those also need a different rabbit address?

Same question goes for my 2 application servers.  If I'm running the same worker on both boxes does it need different addresses?  Some stuff says if you want competing consumers to share an address, but if you want "event" type messages to be delivered to everyone they need to be different addresses.

What if you need both event (broadcast) and command (consumed once) messages sent to a worker cluster?  (Multiple instances of the same workers to handle more load.)

What if I have consumers hosted in the web application directly?  (I'm not sure this is a good idea to start with.)

What about request/response messages?  I assume the responses should go back to the originating web server.  Otherwise the MT request call will never unblock or at best timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each instance of an `IServiceBus` needs it's own RecieveFrom address. And yeah, if there are multiple worker processes, each should have it's own queue. You can use temporary queue for this though in web apps.

For competing consumers, each process/`IServiceBus` that is one of the consumes should be an exact copy. If there's an event that doesn't need to be competing, then it needs to have it's own process.

Comment: What do you mean by a temporary queue?  Just stick a new GUID or something on the end during start up?

Comment: For RabbitMQ, use rabbitmq://localhost/*?temporary=true for a temporary queue